# total path in 3*3 grid

Tags: algorithm

If a person can move only in east and south direction. What are the total number of paths from initial point (0,0) to final point (2,2) in a 3*3 grid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You take 4 steps total.  Choose exactly 2 of those steps to be eastward.

[image]

Comment: This looks correct to me, so why the 2 (anonymous) down-votes I wonder ?

Comment: your answer is correct, but I was thinking, that in the beginning person was out of the grid and so answer is binomial(6,3) and I have downvoted you. Now I realize that I was wrong, but I can't undo my downvote unitll you don't edit your post. Please  edit something and I will upvote your answer. And sorry :(

Answer (score 4):

Depends on how you define your problem. Here are 3 first ways, that pop into my head.

### Vector space problem

1) From point A(0, 0) to point B(2, 2) create a vector **AB**(B_x-A_x, B_y-B_y). This vector exists in affine space and we will introduce custom coordinate axis of "south" and "east" to it. So we get the vector to be `AB = 2 "south" + 2 "east".

To find what are the possible paths: `Permutations[{"south", "south", "east", "east"}]`

```
{{"south", "south", "east", "east"}, {"south", "east", "south", "east"}, {"south", "east", "east", "south"}, {"east", "south", "south", "east"}, {"east", "south", "east", "south"}, {"east", "east", "south", "south"}}
```

To find the length of them: `Length[Permutations[{"south", "south", "east", "east"}]]`

```
6
```

### Algebraic problem

2) Reduce the problem to algebraic form. That is a combinatorial problem, where binomial coefficient `4 choose 2` will give the answer, because you can do 2 different actions total of 4 times.

To calculate: Binomial[4, 2]

```
6
```

### Graphing problem

3) make a graph:

[image]

Then conclude, there are only 6 ways to do it

Comment: The algebraic problem can also be visualized as moving in the Pascal's triangle. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Pascal's+triangle

Answer (score 2):

Explanation: We can encode the way by just storing the steps in the downwards-direction. That, is, we encode just the columns we choose to go one step down:

E.g. `0 1 1 3` means, we go as follows:

```
 0123      = columns 

 v         v = down
 >V        > = right
  v>v
    X
```

So, we have `n` lines (thus `n-1` steps downwards) and in each step we can choose among `m` possibilities (as long as these possibilities are monotonly increasing).

Thus, we can "a priori" choose `n-1` column-numbers from the `m` columns in total, sort them and take them as our way through the grid.

Thus, this experiment corresponds to drawing `n-1` elements from a set with `m` distinct elements, and the order of the elements drawn does not matter (because we just consider them in increasing order). Thus, the total number of possibilities to do this is:

```
/ n-1+m-1 \
|         |
\   n-1   /
```

I realized that my first post contained the wrong details but the idea was the same. Have a look at [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) too see how the idea works.

Comment: @phimuemue -1 binomial(3+3-1,3-1)=binomial(5,2)=10, while you can see in my answer, that there is at least 20 different ways.

Comment: @Ashot: it's a 3x3 grid, not 4x4 - there are only 2 moves east and 2 moves south, hence it's 4C2 = 6 possibilities.

Comment: @Paul you are right. I solve it for 4*4, but my formula is right, while according this solution for 4*4 we getting 10 different ways(binomial(3+3-1,3-1)=10), while there are 20 ways.

Comment: @Ashot Martirosyan: Corrected the formula.

Comment: @phimuemue Now your formula is right. But why different ways of picking  `n-1`  elements without order from m distinct ones is equal to `Binomial(n-1+m-1,n-1)` ? IMHO it's not evidently. Please explain how you are getting that formula without using solution of our problem?

Comment: @Ashot Martirosyan: Have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29

Comment: @phimuemue add this link to your answer and I will upvote your it.

Answer (score 0):

We must go 2 times east and 2 times south. No meter in which order. Let's define east as 1 and south as 0. Then question is equal to how many ways we can write string with length 4, which has two 1-s and two 0-s (for example 1100 or 1001 etc...).

It is equal to Binomial(4,2)=6.

Proof: Assuming, that south=0 and east=1 here are all 6 ways:

> 1100
>
> 1010
>
> 1001
>
> 0110
>
> 0101
>
> 0011